# Reverse for 'profile_settings' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['users\\/profile\\/settings\\/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$']

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have `CustomUser` and `Profile` model. Both tables have a one to one relationship.
I used a `post_save` signal so, whenever a user is created an empty profile is automatically created.
Profile only have an `updateView` because it is already created when a user is created.

Problem : Whenever I access profile, I get this error:

> Reverse for 'profile_settings' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['users\/profile\/settings\/(?P[0-9]+)$']"**

I am definitely making a mistake in template.
Attaching all the relevant code snippets below.

**models.py**

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

class Profile(models.Model):

    user            = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    contact_mobile  = models.CharField(max_length=11, null=True, blank=True)
    shipping_id     = models.ForeignKey(Shipping, related_name='profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    biography = models.CharField(max_length=700),

def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=CustomUser)
```

**views.py**

```
class ProfileSettingsView(UpdateView):
    model = Profile
    form_class = ProfileSettingsForm
    pk_url_kwarg = 'pk'
    context_object_name = 'object'
    template_name = 'profile_settings.html'

    def get_object(self):
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        return get_object_or_404(Profile, id=pk)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        c_object = self.get_object()
        context = super(ProfileSettingsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['user'] = c_object.user
        context['shipping_id'] = c_object.shipping_id
        context['contact_mobile'] = c_object.contact_mobile
        print('------------------------------------------------------')
        print('context: ', context)
        return context

class DashboardView(DetailView):
    model = CustomUser
    pk_url_kwarg = 'pk'
    context_object_name = 'object'
    template_name = 'dashboard.html'
```

**urls.py**

```
path('dashboard/', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
path('profile/settings/<int:pk>', views.ProfileSettingsView.as_view(), name='profile_settings'),
```

**dashboard.html**

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
    <nav class="account-bar">
        <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="{% url 'users:dashboard' %}">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'users:profile_settings' pk=object.id %}">Profile Settings</a></li>                          
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: You're showing us the wrong view code. And the models code is irrelevant. What you need to show is the view code that renders the template where the error occurs (dashboard.html). Anyway, read the error: pk is empty, this means `object.id` is undefined in your template, meaning there's no `object` in your context.

Comment: @dirkgroten I have updated the question with DashboardView.

Comment: How does your dashboard view receive the `CustomUser` pk? Your url pattern to the dashboard view doesn't have a <int:pk> attribute. Is it possible you have another view rendering the dashboard.html?

Comment: You have a URL pattern pointing to `views.dashboard` not `views.DashboardView.as_view()`. This `views.dashboard` is rendering dashboard.html without `object`. You have `def dashboard(request)` in your views.py?

Comment: Thanks, it solved the error.